# Shell script, linux, unix, shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

**$path/shel.sh abcdefgh $path/log.log > file. Log**

What does "abcdefgh" means, is it parameter which provided for that script. (shel.sh)? 
Can any one please explain? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it's parameter, abcdefgh is $1, $path/log.log is $2.

Comment: But how log.log will be $2, its for creating the log file with the output?

Comment: One more thing, is it necessary to have abcdefgh in shel. Sh?

Comment: If you are expanding or clarifying your question, edit the original post rather than put the question in the comments. Makes it easier for people who read it to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$path/shel.sh`: This is the command, unless `$path` gets expanded and word splitting occurs.
- `abcdefgh`: This is the first argument.
- `$path/log.log`: Second argument, unless, again, `$path` gets expanded and word splitting occurs.
- `> file.`: This is a redirection. The output of your command will be redirected to `file.`.
- `Log`: Third argument. Please note that there is a space between `file.` and `Log`, so `Log` will be just another argument.